# не получается установить npm пакеты и даже yarn add выдает ошибку

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarn

Код ошибки:

```
C:\Users\m\Desktop\Anw\projectDg\projectdg>npm i react-icons
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.3
npm WARN Found: typescript@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/typescript
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer typescript@">= 2.7" from fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.3
npm WARN node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
npm WARN   fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@"^6.5.0" from react-dev-utils@12.0.1
npm WARN   node_modules/react-dev-utils
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/react-icons failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-01T20_29_00_058Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\m\Desktop\Anw\projectDg\projectdg>
```

Comment: Попробуйте установить через впн.

Comment: я пробовала не получается. Думаете, может ли выдавать такую ошибку если впн не стабильный